# Browser sends random HTTP message body to my boost.asio server. Can I change this?

Tags: c++, http, boost-asio

FINAL EDIT: Question answered, underwhelming. But you may still find this interesting.

EDIT: Question may have changed slightly. Clarification later in post

I am using an example server from the boost.asio examples which I have built upon. When the browser (Firefox) requests an image or posts something with ajax afterwards it seems to be sending random headers, cut-of words/headers or 'a snippet' of the image previously requested/ajax post. A specific example is that not only the string that I wanted to send to the server via ajax is sent, but also somehow some of the javascript code.

The buffer is set to '\0' before each new request is handled so I don't believe this is the issue. Also, as mentioned, it's not only when ajax is used so if there is a javascript mistake it's probably irrelevant. I have very little experience with the HTTP protocol - maybe there is some solution there that I don't know about?

```
    POST /post HTTP/1.1
    headers

    THIS IS WHAT WAS POSTEDlick = function() {
    ...
    }

    GET /index HTTP/1.1
    headers

    che-Control: max-age=0
```

Here is the c++ code, which is pretty much copied from boost.asio examples:

```
    #include <iostream>

    #include <boost/bind.hpp>
    #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
    #include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
    #include <boost/asio.hpp>

    class connection
        : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<connection>
    {
    public:
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<connection> pointer;

        static pointer create(boost::asio::io_contenxt& io_context)
        {
            return pointer(new connection(io_context));
        }

        tcp::socket& socket() {
            return socket_;
        }

        void start()
        {

            buf[0] = '\0'; //apparently not necessary?

            socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf,length), 
                    boost::bind(&connection::follow_up_write, shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

        }
    private:

        connection(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
            : socket_(io_context)
        {

        }

        follow_up_write(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t by) {
            if(!error) {
                //this is a proposed solution, for simple cout-ing
                //it works, but still problems working with buffer
                //contents (part of EDIT)
                std::string s;
                for(unsigned int i = 0; i < (int)by; i++) {
                    s.push_back(buf[i]);
                }
                //this is for me to check, obviously:
                std::cout << s << std::endl;
                do_something_with_reply dswr(s);

                boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(dswr.answer),
                        boost::bind(&connection::follow_up, shared_from_this()));
            }
            else 
                std::cout << error.message() << std::endl;
        }

        void follow_up() {
            //nothing here yet
        }

        tcp::socket socket_;

        enum {length = 10000}
        char buf[length];

    }
    //not good at naming, don't judge       
    class server
    {
    public:
        server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
            : io_context_(io_context), acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 8080))
        {
            start_accept();
        }

    private:
        void start_accept()
        {
            connection::pointer new_connection = connection::create(io_context_);

            acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection->socket(),
                        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this,
                        new_connection, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }

        void handle_accept(connection::pointer new_connection, const boost::system::error_code& error)
        {
            if(!error) {
                new_connection->start();
            }

            start_accept();
        }

        boost::asio::io_context& io_context_;
        tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

    }

    int main()
    {
        try {
            boost::asio::io_context io_context;

            server server(io_context);

            io_context.run();
        }
        catch(std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

I would like to receive nothing in message body on GET, if possible
and nothing other than what i would like to post in POST.

EDIT: This might actually have to do with how i work with what is received in the buffer. See the example below:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>

    int main() {
        std::ifstream file("file.txt");
        std::string all, txt;
        if(file.is_open()) {
            while(getline(file,txt)) {
                all.append(txt + '\n');
            }
        }

        std::string s;
        s.append("Start");
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < all.length(); i++) {
            s.push_back(all[i]);
        }
        s.append("END" + '\n');

        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
```

This outputs:

```
StartContent of file

Content of file

Content of file
```

but strangely it doesn't show "END".

In a more complicated example My resulting string even has part of the file name at the end of it. In this example it would be "le.txt".

Comment: sounds more like you are reading outside the bounds of your buffers. Show a [mre].

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with boost aiso, but if what's really happening is the browser is sending random requests, then no. You can't change that. You have no control over what the browser does. However, that may not be what's really going on, so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: Don't set the buffer to anything. Just don't access the buffer beyond the number of characters you received and the problem will go away.

Comment: Edited the post. unfortunately the buffer limit thing doesn't seem to be the solution. keep getting "che-Control: max-age=0"

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you have undefined behaviour in `follow_up_write`. [1] `async_write` returns immediately, [2] `asio::buffer` doesn't make a copy of data (it is just wrapper holding pointer to data). [3] in short you have dangling reference.

Comment: There is nothing in this code that processes the Content-length header, which is the only way you can identify the end of the request. See RFC 2246 and successors.

Comment: Yes thank you. It's stilll weird, though.

Comment: No it isn't. There is nothing weird about an implementation of HTTP conforming to its specification, instead of some imaginary system of your own devising.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is underwhelming: user207421 had the solution.

The Content-Length header value is what is needed in order to get the true message body.

Thank you to everyone who took the time to look at this.

PS: the second issue in my post is still weird, but not related to the question.

Comment: What is weird? about what?

Comment: @user207421 As a non-computer scientist almost everything is weird.